# IllegalStateException while attempting to enter synchronized block

Tags: java, concurrency

What does it mean when a IllegalStateException is thrown when entering a synchronized block? I'm seeing this sometimes inside the run-method of a thread:

```
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            int n = 0;
            synchronized (service) { // IllegalStateException
                n = processPendingRequests();
            }

            /*
             * If n > 0, we processed at least one element, in which case we
             * immediately check the queue again until it was empty.
             */
            if (n == 0) {
                sleep();
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can the `service` object cause the `IllegalStateException`? How?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? First guess is that it has nothing to do with the synchronization and is being thrown for a different reason.

Comment: It's actually in the `run` method of a thread. I'll edit the post to be a little more clear.

Comment: If so, why would the debugger stop at the `synchronized` statement?

Comment: Can we see a sample stack trace for this code? I would like to see exactly what line it is occuring on. Also, what kind of object is service?

Comment: I lost the stack trace, but if/when it appears again I will attach it here. `service` is an object which does a whole lot of other things, and other threads are synchronizing on that object as well.

Comment: On a separate note, it looks like you have a request queue that you periodically poll for new entries. You might be better of with a BlockingQueue which is made for this sort of producer/consumer pattern and uses wait/notify (or maybe java.util.concurrent classes, I haven't actually checked) to do this without polling and sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.19), the "synchronized" statement doesn't throw an "IllegalStateException".  Therefore, either the Language Specification is wrong, you're using a non-conforming JVM, or you've misinterpreted the behavior of your program -- as far as I can see.

Comment: I have probably misinterpreted something, yes.